# VIM Marks and Project Management

Tags: vim, project-management, bookmarks

So I've been using NERDTree in vim as it adds great functionality being able to browse around the file system.  And with the Bookmarks capabilities it works great for switching between projects.

However, I've started using Marks more and more in vim and wanted to know if anyone knew of a plugin that allowed you to have sets of marks.  Like I want `C to go to the config file in the project I'm currently working on.  I can set it each time I switch projects, but was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to package them.

In just thinking about it, I think it would be awesome if it would just read a file when you got into a directory (like switching between bookmarks with NERDTree...).

Anyways, anyone know of anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that marks are not stored in the [session](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.4), but are stored in the viminfo file!  So I used the code from your vimrc as a basis and the code found at the bottom of the section on sessions in the [vim help files](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.4) to create a function that will allow me to save save the session and viminfo file.  Creating basic project management that works great for me!

Here is the code I ended up with.

```
if version >= 700
    " localoptions has to be here:
    " for some reason, new session loading code fails to set filetype of files in session
  set sessionoptions=blank,tabpages,folds,localoptions,curdir,resize,winsize,winpos
endif

command! -nargs=1 Project :call LoadProject('<args>')
command! -nargs=+ SaveProject :call SaveProject('<args>')

let s:projectloaded = 0
let s:loadingproject = 0
let s:projectname = ''

function! LoadProject(name)

    let s:projectloaded = 1
    let s:projectname = a:name
    exe "source ~/vimfiles/projects/".a:name.".vim"
    exe "rviminfo! ~/vimfiles/projects/".a:name.".viminfo"

endfunction

function! SaveProject(name)

    if a:name ==# ''
        if s:projectloaded == 1
            let pname = s:projectname
        endif
    else
        let pname = a:name
    endif

    if pname !=# ''
        let s:projectloaded = 0
        let s:projectname = ''
        exe "mksession! ~\\vimfiles\\projects\\".pname.".vim"
        exe "wviminfo! ~\\vimfiles\\projects\\".pname.".viminfo"
    endif

endfunction

autocmd VimLeave * call SaveProject()
```

Comment: Thank you. This piece of code works fine for me, **+1**. Uppercase marks are amazing and now I won't lose any of them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe marks are stored in session files, which may allow you to do what you want. Session management itself is another topic, but you can find some ideas [here](http://lucasoman.blogspot.com/2009/08/vim-tip-session-management.html). This code has been updated to include support for multiple session files, so get the latest in [this](http://github.com/lucasoman/Conf/blob/master/.vimrc) vimrc file.

Comment: Sounds like this will work great I. Combination with NERDTree Bookmarks. With NERDTree you can switch cwd to a Bookmark easily and then you could easily load the session from that working directory. 

I'll give it a try thanks.